# dask: astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'

Tags: dask

for what reason `dask` `astype` givers error if `errors` keyword is specified, while that should work fine according to the [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.astype)?

```py
df['listing_id'] = df['listing_id'].astype('int32', errors='ignore')
```

Here is the error :

> TypeError: astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'

Comment: what version of dask are you running?

Comment: @xibalba1, dask==2.9.0

Answer (score 0):

The doc also says

> This docstring was copied from pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.astype.
>
> Some inconsistencies with the Dask version may exist.

You were warned :)

Comment: Ha!  I love this response :)

Comment: It also says `errors:{‘raise’, ‘ignore’}, default ‘raise’ (Not supported in Dask)`